# Nginx very slow when using query string for cache busting

Tags: nginx

I'm at a bit of a loss here since we've been using this setup for years. For some reason, some - but not all - JS files being loaded using a simple Unix Timestamp query string to bust the cache on our Development server are taking over 20 seconds to load.

The odd thing is, there are other files in the same directory using the same method that load as expected - in milliseconds.

The slow files seem random - on each page load there are at least 3, but not all the same files all the time.

I've tested this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox and the results are the same, so I believe this is server related and not browser based.

[Screenshot of Chrome Network Waterfall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdziV.jpg)

I've tried to remove the query string via Nginx rewrite, turned off compression, upgraded Nginx, but have had no luck solving this.

Any ideas?

nginx-1.25.3-1.el7.ngx.x86_64